# Why we have to mention data type in front of address of the object to access the private members of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, private

I'm trying to access the private members with the help of pointers. I want to know that why we mention dtype in front of (int*)&t?

```
class Test
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    Test() { data = 0; }
    int getData() { return data; }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int* ptr = (int*)&t;
    *ptr = 10;
    cout << t.getData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this makes no sense: ***int* ptr = (int*)&t;***

Comment: Make `data` public if you need access to the value directly. You may create methods for your class that access & manipulate `data`. You should avoid directly manipulating a class's members outside of its own scope.

Answer (score 3):

The access control system applies to *names*.  It is the name `data` which is private, not any variable or associated storage area.  In other words, you can access the variable in other ways so long as you don't use the name `data` to do so.

The purpose of access control is to prevent code from accidentally breaking [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

It's sometimes said that C++ "gives you enough rope to hang yourself",  or "protects against Murphy but not Macchiavelli" -- in other words, you can bypass access control if you really want to. [Link to related article - GotW #76](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm)

Of course, you should try to design your code in such a way that you do not need to bypass access control.

---

In this particular case, the code is well-defined. Since `Test` is a [standard layout class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType), it's guaranteed that there is no padding before the first data member, and [also guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) that this cast produces a pointer to `t.data` which can be used to access said variable.

For more complicated classes your code might not work, if the data member in question doesn't start at the start of the object's storage space.

Answer (score 0):

`(int*)&t` : casts pointer to be a pointer to integer

`int* ptr = (int*)&t;` : it store the pointer of t in ptr

Answer (score 0):

It only works by chance to start with.

`Test` is a primitive class with no inheritance involved, no virtual methods, compiled without RTTI support, or anything else which could bloat the in memory representation.

In this trivial example, the only member variable is at the same address as the entire object. That is extremely unsafe to depend on, since it's undefined behavior for anything more complex.

Try e.g. now bringing inheritance and virtual methods into your test. Suddenly the first few bytes of your object are no longer the first member variable (that's where the compiler will typically place the VPTR), and you test crashes horribly.

Or make you member variable a static instead, now your object itself is actually empty and you access heap control structures instead, which causes not necessarily an immediate crash, but heap corruptions which are far worse. Well, in this case `t` was stack allocated so you only corrupt your stack instead (which is slightly less worse), but if it was heap allocated this would have become critical.